# Deploying ASP.Net Project to Ubuntu server using Mono

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, mono

I have developed an ASP.net 4.5 Project using Visual Studio 2013 and I am assigned to deploy it on our Ubuntu server.

Like what other tutorials said I need to use Mono to make this possible. I think I followed those steps but when I try to open the page, it gives me this error.

[image: error]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please add your code that causes the exception + the exception stacktrace.

Comment: Hi, Sorry but I'm not also sure if this is a code issue or a server issue because the website runs perfectly on my local machine but it only got this issue when I tried to run on the ubuntu server. I'm just hoping that somebody here has this problem also.

Comment: On the screenshot I see the "Exception stack trace: ...". Take that and post here, it may help to find where the issue belongs to.

Comment: but it is the complete error i've got. The stacktrace doesn't also shows the line where the error is. The picture I post is the complete stacktrace I've got.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exception when deploying my application, but to a Windows Server. The problem was that some dlls references pointed to my local assemblies. (example: System.Web.Http.WebHost was referenced to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll, so in the server this LoadException ocurred because this dll was missing.)

So the generic answer is: There is some dll missing. Compare the references in your project with the bin folder in the server. If there's some reference that points to local machine, change the property `CopyLocal` to `true`, so when you compile and publish the dll will be copied to the output directory.

I don't use Mono, but how this same problem ocurred to me in a Windows Server, may be the same problem with you in a Linux Machine.

If the probem persists, try to create a simple project, with just one page and a few dependencies just to see if the asp.net works fine in this server.

Comment: @Dave, have you tested it?